# RSS лента в MODX посредством getResources

Tags: modx, link, компоновщик, rss

Создал ресурс rssNews.rss :

```
    <rss
    xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    xmlns:turbo="http://turbo.yandex.ru"
    version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>[[*longtitle]]</title>
        <link>[[~[[*id]]?scheme=`full`]]</link>
        <description>[[*introtext:cdata]]</description>
        <language>ru</language>
        <ttl>120</ttl>
        [[!getResources?
          &tpl=`rssItem`
          &parents=`2,3`
          &depth=`5`
          &limit=`10`
          &includeContent=`1`
          &includeTVs=`1`
          &showHidden=`1`
          &hideContainers=`1`
          &useWeblinkUrl=`1`
          &scheme=`full`
        ]]
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Далее чанк rssItem:

```
<item turbo="true"><!--Информация о странице-->
    <title>[[+pagetitle:cdata]]</title>
    <link>[[++site_url]][[~[[+id]]]]</link>
    <description>
        [[+introtext:cdata]]
    </description>
    <pubDate>[[+publishedon:strtotime:date=`%a, %d %b %Y %R:%S`]] +0400</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">[[++site_url]][[~[[+id]]]]</guid>
    <dc:creator>
    [[+createdby:userinfo=`username`]]
    </dc:creator>
    <turbo:content>
        [[+content]]
    </turbo:content>
</item>
```

В итоге в валидаторе постоянно ошибка:

> Не удалось скачать изображение (16 ошибок)
> https://site.ru/themes-category/science/assets/gallery/14/59.jpg ...

Ну оно и понятно, потому что он изображение пытается брать не с той директивы, а надо:
**https://site.ru/assets/gallery/14/59.jpg**

Как настроить (полагаю, что link в чанке) так, чтобы линковка была нормальной?

Comment: Вот есть статья по настройке турбо страниц на modx [Создание Яндекс турбо страниц на modx tickets](https://groovyweb.ru/blog/sozdanie-yandeks-turbo-stranicz-v-modx-revo-2-5-6-s-tickets)